# Filter Google maps markers with input sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I am working on a new Wordpress site which my client is going to publish available apartments on. These objects is going to be published with Advanced Custom Fields using the "Map" field. For each new object published, a marker appears on the Google Map on the page.

Now, my problem is, users must be able to filter these markers depending on three things: A minimum number of rooms, minimum area, max rent/price. So to be more specific. If the user sets the minimum number of rooms to 3 in the input slider it is supposed to only show apartments with at least 3 rooms and the same with the other filter options. This is not the problem tho, the user also needs to be able to filter on all the three different options at once. Like this; Minimum number of rooms = 3, Max rent = 1000, Minimum area = 30sq.m. Now it should only show markers on the map that matches the filter values.

This is what I have done so far:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="range1">
 <label></label>
 <output for="object-room" class="room-output"></output>
 <input type="range" name="object-room" min="1" max="20" step="1" value="1">
 </div>

 <div class="range2">
 <label></label>
 <output for="object-size" class="size-output"></output>
 <input type="range" name="object-size" min="15" max="300" step="5" value="1">
 </div>

 <div class="range3">
 <label></label>
 <output for="object-price" class="price-output"></output>
 <input type="range" name="object-price" min="1000" max="20000" step="500" value="4500">
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  // Filter markers
  $marker.each(function(i, obj) {
    var objPrice = $(this).data("price");
    var objSize = $(this).data("size");
    var objRoom = $(this).data("room");

    $("[name=object-price]").on("change", function() {
      $("[for=object-price]").val(this.value + ' kr');
      var priceVal = this.value;

      if ( priceVal >= objPrice ) {
        marker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        marker.setVisible(false);
      }

    }).trigger("change");

  });
```

Comment: Does your variable `$marker` contain all markers?

Comment: @weigreen Yes, I get them like this; var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: @wegreen https://jsfiddle.net/7ykreetg/  I tried to replicate it as much as I could, don't know how I should add the markers to the map in the fiddle. The objects are added in wordpress and then I call the Custom field to make the object appear as a marker on the map. Hope this is enough :)


EDIT: I forgot to add that, each object gets an individual price/area/room data type and these are also added as a Custom Field in Wordpress. This is what i'm trying to filter with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following step:

1. Add a array `var markers = []` which can be accessible to global. (same usage as your `map.markers` but try not direct add things to SDK)
2. In your `add_marker()` create each marker and push it to `markers` array. You may use below code to make it easier later.

---

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(); //with your attribute.
var markerWithData = {'marker': marker, 'price': 123, ...} // all you data belong to that marker.
markers.push(markerWithData );
```

3. Add new function `filterMarker()`: this function get your filter data and loop through `markers` and set visible at array item's `marker` attribute.

---

```
for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
    //Check markers[i] need to be display or not.
    if(needDisplay){
        markers[i].marker.setVisible(true);
    }else{
        markers[i].marker.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

I know this is not clear but i don't know how to descriptive better. If you have any question please comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

It's working now and this is my solution:

**jQuery**

```
    var markers = []; //Global var 

    function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

      // var
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
      var icon = $marker.attr('data-icon');


      // create marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map,
              icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 3,
                strokeColor: '#f04a3e',
                fillColor: '#f04a3e',
                strokeWeight: 6
              },
      });

      // add to array
      map.markers.push( marker );
      markers.push( marker );

      //Filter markers
      $marker.each(function(i, obj) {
        var objPrice = $(this).data("price");
        var objSize = $(this).data("kvm");
        var objRoom = $(this).data("room");

        $(".filterSlider").on("change", function () {
            filterAll();
        });

        filterAll();

        function filterAll () {
            $('.filterSlider').each(function (i, obj) {
                var priceVal = $('#price').val();
                var roomVal = $('#room').val();
                var sizeVal = $('#kvm').val();
                var outputVal = $(this).prev().val(this.value);

                if ( priceVal >= objPrice && roomVal <= objRoom && sizeVal <= objSize ) {
                  marker.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                  marker.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }

      });
      }
```